# What are the Wolfram Workbench 3.0 Special Preferences?

Tags: workbench

What are the Wolfram Workbench 3.0 Special Preferences:

- Workspace DSEs;
- Enable Advanced Technology.

The preferences are not described in the help system, the help system explains the preferences as they were in Workbench 2.0.

Comment: Does this have any useful info?  http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/961186

Comment: Not really, it is mostly info about paclets.